# Angular : is an app crawlable with no href but only ng-click function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, seo, web-crawler

I would like to know if my app would be crawlable if I do not use href on my link but only a data-ng-click function. For example, will the page2/index.html will be visit by the google bot if I code it the way below, and if not, what should I put in the href so it is?

The HTML

```
<a href="" data-ng-click="go('/page2')"> go page 2 </a>
```

The routes

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/page2',
    {
        templateUrl: 'views/app/page2/index.html'
    })
});
```

And the GO() function

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $location) {

    $rootScope.go = function (route) {
        $location.path(route);
    }
});
```

Thanks guys

Comment: angular app (and every spa app) is never crawlable because content are injected into DOM by javascript and not by server side processes

Comment: @tarini please post this as the answer

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not be indexed. You should at least create a sitemap.xml.

Answer (score -1):

angular app (and every spa app) is never crawlable because content are injected into DOM by javascript and not by server side processes

Comment: That's not true. Google is rendering JavaScript since about a year ago.  http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.no/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html

Comment: Google can't rendering javascript because it can't trigger any possible events in my page. How they can "know" that some particular view is rendered when user click on a particular button in my page? There are some many aspects when dealing with user interfaces and with user gestures that no one could never craws a dynamic website in a good way.

Comment: Thanks.
I actually  added a href and removed the ng-click:
<a href="#/page2">go page 2</a> 

Not sure yet if it makes the site crawlable but I think so. I'm pretty sure the bot can go through all my pages this way.

Comment: @StinsonMaster could you please remove downvote? you didn't reply to my comment